# To navigate from one movieclip to other by pressing TAB in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In a registration page,i want to move to next field,when i click tab from keyboard.I have implemented ENTER key for submnission,but i cant move to next field when pressing TAB

Comment: try to give your fields a `tabIndex` property: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabIndex

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tabIndex to sequential values should be enough, maybe tabEnabled too.....

```
textfieldOne.tabIndex=1;
textfieldTwo.tabIndex=2;
textfieldOne.tabEnabled=true;
textfieldTwo.tabEnabled=true;
```